Formulario campo label select
Tengo un formulario con un campo tipo input y otro tipo select, estoy realizando la transición del placeholder con la etiqueta label y me funciona bien, pero con el select siempre vuelve a su posición original aunque ya esté seleccionado un campo
ejemplo:
Quisiera saber si se puede hacer que el select funcione igual que el input saludos y gracias


.buscador {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      gap: 10px;

      .form-group {
        position: relative;
        margin: 20px 0;
      }

      label {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        left: 10px;
        color: #aaa;
        transition: 0.2s ease all;
        pointer-events: none; /* Evita que el label capture eventos */
      }
      input,
      select {
        padding: 10px;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 5px;
        width: 100%;
        background: var(--input-color);
        color: var(--text-color);
      }

      input:focus + label,
      input:not(:placeholder-shown) + label,
      select:focus + label
  /*     select:not([value='']) + label */ {
        top: -18px;
        left: 10px;
        font-size: 12px;
        color: #333; /* Color del label cuando está en foco */
      }

    }
 <form action="">
            <section class="buscador">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="search" id="buscar" name="buscar" required placeholder="" />
                <label for="buscar">Frase a Buscar </label>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <select name="tipo" id="tipo" required placeholder="">
                  <option value="" selected></option>
                  <option value="users">Por Usuario</option>
                  <option value="repos">Por Repositorios</option>
                  <option value="topics">Por Topics (separados con espacios)</option>
                </select>
                <label for="tipo">Tipo de Búsqueda </label>
              </div>
              <input type="submit" value="Buscar" />
            </section>
</form>




Algo así buscas?


.buscador {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 10px;

  .form-group {
    position: relative;
    margin: 20px 0;
  }

  label {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    color: #aaa;
    transition: 0.2s ease all;
    pointer-events: none; /* Evita que el label capture eventos */
  }
  input,
  select {
    padding: 10px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    background: var(--input-color);
    color: var(--text-color);
  }

  input:focus + label,
  input:not(:placeholder-shown) + label,
  select.focus:focus + label,
  select:has(option[value='']:not(:checked)) + label ,
  select.focus:has(option[value='']:not(:checked)) + label {
    top: -18px;
    left: 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #333; /* Color del label cuando está en foco */
  }

}
<section class="buscador">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="search" id="buscar" name="buscar" required placeholder="" />
        <label for="buscar">Frase a Buscar </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <select class ="focus" name="tipo2" id="tipo2" required placeholder="">
          <option value="" selected></option>
          <option value="users">Por Usuario</option>
          <option value="repos">Por Repositorios</option>
          <option value="topics">Por Topics (separados con espacios)</option>
        </select>
        <label for="tipo2">Tipo de Búsqueda con focus </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <select name="tipo" id="tipo" required placeholder="">
          <option value="" selected></option>
          <option value="users">Por Usuario</option>
          <option value="repos">Por Repositorios</option>
          <option value="topics">Por Topics (separados con espacios)</option>
        </select>
        <label for="tipo">Tipo de Búsqueda </label>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" value="Buscar" />
    </section>



El selector select:has(option[value='']:not(:checked)) + label seleccionara los labels que tengan como hermano inmediatamente anterior un select, que contenga un option que tenga la propiedad value = '' y a su vez este no este seleccionado.
En este caso la pseudoclase focus no es importante.

Si excelente gracia, pero si se necesita el "select:focus + labe"l, ya que con él se mejora la experiencia de usuario

uh? porque necesitas el focus para 'mejorar la experiencia del usuario'? no tiene sentido eso

Ejecuta la edición del código y júzgalo por ti mismo.  Gracias por la solución y saludos

@QuinteroDeivy ah si, tenes razon
